# Ubuntu 17.10 Cherry Trail problem with sound - funny and sad

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth

I got a problem! Of course I do, doesnt I?

I got:

1. No sound working on my ubuntu.
2. No bluetooth working on my ubuntu.
3. No mmc working on my  ubuntu.

Will I find here a proud knight thet will find a solution for my problems? Propably will kill the dragon too if u get the joke.

Sooo, let's begin!

> inxi -F

Gave me this beautiful output, as you may guess this is kind of my hardware and software that am very proud of! I trully do!

> System:    Host: roman-KIANO-SlimNote-14-2 Kernel: 4.13.0-32-generic x86_64
>              bits: 64
>
> ```
>        Desktop: Gnome 3.26.2 Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
> ```
>
> Machine:   Device: laptop System: KIANO product: KIANO SlimNote 14 2 serial: N/A
>
> ```
>        Mobo: AMI model: Cherry Trail CR serial: N/A
>
>        UEFI: N/A v: WH-BI-14-Y116CR210-C34A-022-B date: 03/28/2017
> ```
>
> CPU:       Quad core Intel Atom x5-Z8350 (-MCP-) cache: 1024 KB
>
> ```
>        clock speeds: max: 1920 MHz 1: 1440 MHz 2: 1440 MHz 3: 1440 MHz
>
>        4: 1440 MHz
> ```
>
> Graphics:  Card: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers
>
> ```
>        Display Server: wayland (X.Org 1.19.5 ) driver: i915
>
>        Resolution: 1366x768@59.80hz
>
>        OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (Cherrytrail)
>        version: 4.5 Mesa 17.2.4
> ```
>
> Audio:     Card-1 Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio driver: HdmiLpeAudio
>
> ```
>        Card-2 bytcr-rt5651 driver: bytcr-rt5651
>
>        Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-32-generic
> ```
>
> Network:   Card: Failed to Detect Network Card!
>
> Drives:    HDD Total Size: NA (-)
>
> ```
>        ID-1: /dev/mmcblk0 model: N/A size: 31.3GB
> ```
>
> Partition: ID-1: / size: 29G used: 9.8G (37%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/mmcblk0p2
>
> RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
>
> Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 66.0C mobo: N/A
>
> ```
>        Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
> ```
>
> Info:      Processes: 267 Uptime: 1:17 Memory: 1433.5/1908.1MB
>
> ```
>        Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.37
> ```

from the other hand command:

> wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh

uploaded this info into this website :)

> http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0aaf9e509fb6f8725b424e3b2dd3be1c7fc4e0d0

From the second other hand command:

> dmesg

gave me this Cancer and it's so much longer!

> [   86.188761]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> [  320.914532]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> ...
>
> [  849.524378] perf: interrupt took too long (2521 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79250
>
> [  966.227723]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> ...
>
> [  972.301827]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> [ 1184.364502] kauditd_printk_skb: 366 callbacks suppressed
>
> [ 1184.364505] audit: type=1400 audit(1518298501.008:423): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mimeinfo.cache" pid=7857 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0[ 1325.398791]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> [ 1325.399186]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> ...
>
> [ 1409.299620]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> [ 1432.583765] perf: interrupt took too long (3205 > 3151), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62250
>   [ 1506.696836]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> ...
>
> [ 2068.770969]  Audio Port: ASoC: no backend DAIs enabled for Audio Port
>
> [ 2239.995919] perf: interrupt took too long (4019 > 4006), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49750

From the other hand command

```
lspci
```

looks fine like my girlfriend - I got none. But maby you will find out problem here.

> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
>
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers (rev 36)
>
> 00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
>
> 00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 36)
>
> 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36)
>
> 00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 36)
>
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)

From the forth hand - yea, funny. Another command

> aplay -l

Gave me list of my devices - sorry for foregin laguage

> **** Lista PLAYBACK urządzeń ****
>
> karta 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], urządzenie 0: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel > HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
>
> Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
>
> Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
>
> karta 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], urządzenie 1: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
>
> Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
>
> Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
>
> karta 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], urządzenie 2: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio]
>
> Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
>
> Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
>
> karta 1: bytcrrt5651 [bytcr-rt5651], urządzenie 0: Audio (*) []
>
> Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
>
> Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0
>
> karta 1: bytcrrt5651 [bytcr-rt5651], urządzenie 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
>
> Urządzenia podrzędne: 1/1
>
> Urządzenie podrzędne #0: subdevice #0

But my Youboon2 got nice command like

> lsmod

thats gave me relative short output :)

> Module                  Size  Used by
>
> xt_CHECKSUM            16384  1
>
> iptable_mangle         16384  1
>
> xt_tcpudp              16384  5
>
> ipt_MASQUERADE         16384  1
>
> nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4    16384  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
>
> xt_comment             16384  8
>
> iptable_nat            16384  1
>
> nf_conntrack_ipv4      16384  2
>
> nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
>
> nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
>
> nf_nat                 28672  2 nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
>
> nf_conntrack          131072  5 nf_conntrack_ipv4,ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat
>
> libcrc32c              16384  2 nf_conntrack,nf_nat
>
> bridge                143360  0
>
> stp                    16384  1 bridge
>
> llc                    16384  2 bridge,stp
>
> iptable_filter         16384  1
>
> bnep                   20480  2
>
> nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
>
> axp288_adc             16384  0
>
> axp288_fuel_gauge      20480  0
>
> axp288_charger         20480  0
>
> axp20x_pek             16384  0
>
> industrialio           69632  2 axp288_adc,axp288_fuel_gauge
>
> extcon_axp288          16384  0
>
> snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651    16384  0
>
> gpio_keys              20480  0
>
> intel_rapl             20480  0
>
> intel_powerclamp       16384  0
>
> coretemp               16384  0
>
> kvm_intel             204800  0
>
> kvm                   581632  1 kvm_intel
>
> irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
>
> unit_atom_debug       16384  0
>
> crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
>
> crc32_pclmul           16384  0
>
> ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
>
> pcbc                   16384  0
>
> aesni_intel           188416  0
>
> aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
>
> uvcvideo               90112  0
>
> crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
>
> glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
>
> cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
>
> videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
>
> intel_cstate           20480  0
>
> videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
>
> videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
>
> input_leds             16384  0
>
> videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
>
> joydev                 20480  0
>
> videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
>
> media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
>
> hci_uart              106496  0
>
> btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
>
> serdev                 20480  1 hci_uart
>
> intel_soc_pmic_bxtwc    16384  0
>
> intel_hid              16384  0
>
> dw_dmac                16384  0
>
> dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
>
> extcon_intel_int3496    16384  0
>
> axp20x_i2c             16384  0
>
> sparse_keymap          16384  1 intel_hid
>
> btqca                  16384  1 hci_uart
>
> intel_pmc_ipc          20480  1 intel_soc_pmic_bxtwc
>
> snd_intel_sst_acpi     16384  1
>
> axp20x                 24576  1 axp20x_i2c
>
> btintel                16384  1 hci_uart
>
> r8723bs               602112  0
>
> snd_intel_sst_core     77824  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
>
> bluetooth             540672  11 hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm
>
> snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform   102400  3 snd_intel_sst_core
>
> snd_soc_rt5651         81920  1
>
> intel_cht_int33fe      16384  0
>
> cfg80211              610304  1 r8723bs
>
> snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5651
>
> snd_soc_sst_match      16384  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
>
> ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
>
> snd_soc_core          229376  3 
>   snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651,snd_soc_rt5651
>
> snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
>
> ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
>
> snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
>
> pwm_lpss_platform      16384  0
>
> 8250_dw                16384  0
>
> snd_hdmi_lpe_audio     24576  2
>
> spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
>
> pwm_lpss               16384  1 pwm_lpss_platform
>
> snd_pcm                98304  6
>
> snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_rt5651
>
> tpm_crb                16384  0
>
> snd_seq_midi           16384  0
>
> snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
>
> snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
>
> snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
>
> snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
>
> dptf_power             16384  0
>
> snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
>
> int3406_thermal        16384  0
>
> int3400_thermal        16384  0
>
> acpi_pad              180224  0
>
> acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
>
> int3403_thermal        16384  0
>
> snd                    81920  13 snd_compress,snd_seq,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_timer,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
>
> soc_button_array       16384  0
>
> processor_thermal_device    16384  0
>
> mac_hid                16384  0
>
> intel_int0002_vgpio    16384  1
>
> soundcore              16384  1 snd
>
> mei_txe                20480  0
>
> int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
>
> intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  1 processor_thermal_device
>
> mei                    98304  1 mei_txe
>
> lpc_ich                24576  0
>
> ndiswrapper           282624  0
>
> parport_pc             32768  0
>
> ppdev                  20480  0
>
> lp                     20480  0
>
> parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
>
> binder_linux          102400  0
>
> ashmem_linux           16384  0
>
> ip_tables              24576  3 iptable_mangle,iptable_filter,iptable_nat
>
> x_tables               40960  7 xt_comment,iptable_mangle,ip_tables,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_CHECKSUM
>
> autofs4                40960  2
>
> hid_generic            16384  0
>
> usbhid                 49152  0
>
> hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
>
> i915                 1798144  36
>
> mmc_block              36864  3
>
> i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
>
> drm_kms_helper        167936  1 i915
>
> syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>
> sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>
> sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>
> fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
>
> drm                   356352  28 i915,drm_kms_helper
>
> video                  40960  2 int3406_thermal,i915
>
> sdhci_acpi             16384  0
>
> sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_acpi

From the another hand commang:

But I know, this may not give you nessesary information. If you need more information about hardware I am using I would be glad to help you with nessesary information.

What I tryed?

> Alsamixer install, reinstall - check; not working;
>
> Pavucontrol install, reinstall - check; not working;
>
> Windows drivers drive by ndiswrappper - check; not working;

Answer (score 3):

i have a very similar setup with bytcr-rt5651 and ubuntu 17.10 this fixed mine:

1. in etc/modprobe.d create file blacklist_hdmi.conf with contents:

   ```
   blacklist snd_hdmi_lpe_audio
   ```
2. download and run this linixium sh script:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99O3A0dDe67VUNMV2xfVjJKeVk/edit

3. in /usr/share/alsa/ucm/ create a bytcr-rt5651 folder with contents:

   asound.state

   bytcr-rt5651.conf

   HiFi.conf
4. sudo alsa force-reload
5. rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
6. pulseaudio -k
7. reboot
8. open pavucontrol and set configuration profile to HiFi and change output from headphones to speakers.

Comment: It didnt solved my sound problem.

I can tell you straight, pavucontrol works and i settled profile for HiFi and changed output as you told me to do.  You made great identification of my problem in '1.'.

It did like alot - I mean i see spikes of sound on my monitor - but the speakers are still quiet. Buuut when I plug in headset - and set it all to headset in pavucontrol - I hear electric noise when moving my mouse or hitting my keyboard. Sounds more like old CCCP ground controll comunication with Sputnik.

I cant lie to you. It's progress but still got no sound.

Comment: More than that. I tryed even diffrent drivers from https://github.com/plbossart/UCM/tree/master/bytcr-rt5651 and still got NADA sound on my speakers nor headphones. I dont hear even sputnik noises on these drivers I guess. It may be problem with my youbountu settings, I will propably like try to install this new one Canonical Beaver from the ground, maby it will fix the problem. I don't rly know. I know that hardware works for sure - on windows! Problem has to be somewhere with the software or may be with the scripts. If you got any ideas I will follow your advices.

Answer (score 1):

Use Linuxium respinned Ubuntu iso( http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2019/03/ubuntu-announced-new-point-releases-for.html ) if sound not working do the steps suggested by Dave Slash Knoll . 
I'm using a Baytrail device and i got working speakers with doing above method .

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.