# Ubuntu 18.04 sound problem in some desktops only

Tags: sound

I have no sound output in Ubuntu 18.04 when I am using Gnome 3 or KDE Plasma or Budgei. However, with the MATE desktop or Unity there are no problems with sound. I tried `force-reload alsa` and installing pulseaudio.

My system is Iball compbook Excelance with Atom Z3735f Baytrail processor. I’m using Linuxium Ubuntu 18.04 beta 2 fourth look ISO for Baytrail devices.

[image: Screenshot of notifications panel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Fix for this from [Ubuntu 17.10 Cherry Trail problem with sound - funny and sad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004998/ubuntu-17-10-cherry-trail-problem-with-sound-funny-and-sad)

1. in etc/modprobe.d create file blacklist_hdmi.conf with contents:

   blacklist snd_hdmi_lpe_audio
2. download and run this linixium sh script:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99O3A0dDe67VUNMV2xfVjJKeVk/edit

3. in /usr/share/alsa/ucm/ create a bytcr-rt5651 folder with contents:

   asound.state

   bytcr-rt5651.conf

   HiFi.conf

   4. sudo alsa force-reload
      rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
      pulseaudio -k
   5. reboot
      open pavucontrol and set configuration profile to HiFi and change output from headphones to speakers.